# Uncaught ReferenceError: finalStr is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am very new to the JS and I am facing one issue with global variable. Below is what I am trying to do but at run time it is giving error "Uncaught ReferenceError: finalStr is not defined". Below is my code:

```
finalStr: '',
    getStatus: function (ConditionTrue) {
                str = '';

    if (data) {
        switch (ConditionTrue) {
            case UPLOADED:
                str = '* ' + FileName + ' has been uploaded at ' + Date;
                finalStr = finalStr + '\n' + str + " ";
                break;
            case CHECKS:
                str = '* ' + FileName + ' failed' + Date + '\n' + Comments;
                finalStr = finalStr + '\n' + str + " ";
                break;
            case VALIDATION:
                str = '* ' + FileName + ' has been uploaded at ' + Date + '\n' +'* Validating';
                finalStr = finalStr + '\n' + str + " ";
                break;

            default:
                str = str + '\n' + Comments ? Comments : Date + ' ' + FileName + ' ' + Status;
                finalStr = finalStr + '\n' + str + " ";
            break;
        }
    }
    area.setValue(finalStr); ---> Giving error here -  Uncaught ReferenceError: finalStr is not defined

},
```

Comment: Try using `this.finalStr`

Comment: You've pasted incomplete code. What's `area`, what's `setValue`, where is this global variable defined? Relevant fragments are missing.

Comment: @Dario Could you give me syntax of this line : finalStr = finalStr + '\n' + str + " "; line ? Should it be like this.finalStr = this.finalStr + '\n' + str + " "; ? 

and area.setValue(this.finalStr);                            

I wanted to keep this as global variable that's why keeping this as out of method

Comment: It looks like `finalStr` is a property of your object, the same object with getStatus method. In this sense, it's not a global variable and need to be accessed with `this.finalStr`. If you want a global variable, just declare it outside of your object ```var finalStr = ''``` and then you can avoid using `this.`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you needed to reference `finalStr` as `this.finalStr`.

Comment: Could you please give me syntax of finalStr = finalStr + '\n' + str + " "; line ? Should it be like this.finalStr = this.finalStr + '\n' + str + " "; ? I wanted to keep this as global variable that's why keeping this as out of method scope.